# Parsing a list nested within a dictionary for words with similar characters in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, parsing, nested

As my first personal project I am building a Wordle "solver" that comes up with a first guess word then takes an input of the letters that were correct in the word then searches the word list for words with similar characters. To do this I stored each word in a dictionary with the key being the word and the value being each character in the word i.e dodge: [d, o, d, g, e]. I am currently experimenting to get code running that parses through the values of the dictionary to match the characters to the inputted letters but am stumped on how to search through the lists within the dictionary as a loop.

Here's my code for inputting the correct letters:

```
correct_letters_1 = list(letters for letters in input("Input corrects letters: ").strip().split())
```

Here's one of my attempts at parsing the dictionary:

```
for letters in correct_letters_1: 
    if letters in word_dictionary.values(): 
       print("yes")
```

I'm pretty sure this problem has something to do with my code parsing the entire lists within the dictionary rather than each individual character but even when I try inputting the whole word, i.e Input Correct Letters: d o d g e; I still don't have any output.

If someone could put a beginner on the right track it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you just enter the letters/word as a single string w/o any spaces?

Comment: Because then the outputted list would be the one word within a list rather than the individual characters within the word. ['aeiou'] rather than ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']. Thus, as far as I can discern, meaning that I can't scan the dictionary for the individual characters rather than the word itself.

Comment: Try `for letter in "aeiou":`

Comment: another commenter pointed out to me that if I use `correct_letters_1 = list(input("Input correct letters: ").strip() then I can type the letters as one string w/o spaces. Thanks for your comment though!

Comment: You can leave off the enclosing `list` and it will work just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking to compare the whole list, rather than the `letters`:

```py
correct_letters_1 = list(input("Enter correct letters: ").strip())

# correct_letters_1 is a whole list
if correct_letters_1 in word_dictionary.values():
    print("yes")
```

---

```py
# Inputting "abc"
>>> correct_letters_1
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> word_dictionary
{'abc': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
>>> correct_letters_1 in word_dictionary.values()
True
```

---

To check if the user's guess is a [subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#Examples_of_subsets) of any of the words:

```py
correct_letters_1 = list(input("Enter correct letters: ").strip())
let_set = set(correct_letters_1)

word_dictionary = {'abc': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'abcde': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                   'ab': ['a', 'b'],
                   'test': ['t', 'e', 's', 't']}

# Check to see if correct_letters_1 is a subset of any word in the dictionary
close_words = ["".join(x) for x in word_dictionary.values() if let_set <= set(x)]
```

Which can be simplified to:

```py
correct_letters_1 = input("Enter correct letters: ").strip()
let_set = set(correct_letters_1)

words = ["abc", "test", "ab"]

# Check to see if correct_letters_1 is a subset of any word in the list words
close_words = [x for x in words if let_set <= set(x)]
```

Comment: That works for checking the whole word but where I'm confused is how I can then go on to check the individual characters in the list rather than the whole list itself. Is there any way to implement your approach by splitting the lists into their component parts? I really appreciate you taking the time to respond!

Comment: No worries, what exactly do you want to do with the letters? Are you trying to get a results from the dictionary that matches each letter? or matches multiple letters?

Comment: So my end goal is to return the keys that have matching letters to correct_letters_1 in the values. For example, if I type in dodge, and there are three correct letters, odg, I want to compare those letters to the letters in the values of word_dictionary and return those matching keys. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think so, updating answer now

Comment: That works! Thanks so much!! What should I read up on to understand exactly what you did? Should I just read the set documentation or about data structures?

Comment: No worries, note that a set has no duplicates, so if you enter `"aaaaa"` it will match with `"abc"`. You should have a look at sets and subsets (math) just to understand how they work. Strings are also kind of like lists, so you never needed to so `list("a word")`. Hence why the last example works. You might want to look at Python list comprehension too. Keep asking questions :)